# Reducing and solving a 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to learn differential equations. Think about a second order ODE (string example, everything w.r.t. t):

> $$x'' = -k(x - 2) - lx'$$

if I were to reduce that to a first order system with variables x and v = x', would the ODE system be this?

> $$ v = x'$$
>
> $$ x = 2 - lv/k$$

Now, I end up solving that x = 2, but I'm trying to learn the terminology and different stages here to think correctly, and even though I might be able to solve such things, I'm not sure I would be able to correctly tell what the first order system is.

Comment: What happened to $x''$ of the differential equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the ODE be:
$$x''(t)=-k(x(t)-2) -\lambda x'(t)$$
(here I let $\lambda:=l$).
Then set:
\begin{align}
v(t) & :=x'(t) \\
u(t) & :=x(t), 
\end{align}
so to obtain the equivalent first order ODE system:
\begin{align}
u'(t) & =v(t)\\
v'(t) & =-k(u(t)-2) -\lambda v(t). 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason why we use $u(t)$ even though we only set it equal to $x(t)$? I guess I'm asking, what if I want to express the system with the variables $x$ and $v$, what would I set $x$ equal to in the system?

Comment: @Roope: I guess it is simply a standard usage. If you do not "rename" $x(t)$ you simply write $x'(t)=v(t)$ and $v'(t)$ in terms of $x(t)$ and $v(t)$.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, thanks.